# Is it possible to call a test from within another test using Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some redundant code, especially with the last test and it would be nice if I could clean it up by just calling other tests within that last test.

```
test "found login element successfully" do
  user = @driver.find_element(name: 'username')
  assert_not_nil user, "found username element"
end

test "entered login successfully" do
  user = @driver.find_element(name: 'username')
  user.send_keys "test"
  assert_equal "test", user.attribute("value"), "username text entered successfully"
end

test "found password element successfully" do
  password = @driver.find_element(name: 'password')
  assert_not_nil password
end

test "entered password successfully" do
  password = @driver.find_element(name: 'password')
  password.send_keys "test*"
  assert_equal "test*", password.attribute("value"), "password text entered successfully"
end

test "logged in successfully" do
  user = @driver.find_element(name: 'username')
  user.send_keys "test"
  password = @driver.find_element(name: 'password')
  password.send_keys "test"
  password.submit
  sleep 5
  assert_equal 'reddit: the front page of the internet', @driver.title
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beautiful thing about minitest or any other ruby based testing library is that ... it's just Ruby! So make a method to do what you'd like:

```
def get_username
  @driver.find_element(name: 'username').attribute("value")
end 

def set_username(value)
  user = @driver.find_element(name: 'username')
  user.send_keys value
end

def get_password
  @driver.find_element(name: 'password').attribute("value")
end

def set_password(value)
  password = @driver.find_element(name: 'password')
  password.send_keys "test*"
end

# etc ...
```

The above can be inlined right in your test file, or brought in via `require` if you want to move it into it's own file.